# C# Ftp uploading when network break, how to resume?

Tags: c#, ftp, upload, ftpwebrequest, resume

I am using FtpWebRequest, asyn method to upload files, but when I try to break the network(like Network cable unplugged), the file transfered part(maybe 20%) in win ftp server is uncountable size(cannot get size), so I can't resume this upload.

But when i try to reupload again call the:
`Request.EndGetRequestStream(ar)`, it has an exception and the file part in server is countable again.

I think maybe some stream.close() issues cause the problem.

My question is how to resume upload when the network is reconnected?
Thanks!

---

After I split filestream to upload seperately(close requeststream every split), still find the file was locked by win server IIS after network breaks.

Any suggustion?

Comment: Your issue is not related to any programming language. How would you resume an FTP session anyway?

Comment: @PepitoSh the problem is if I disconnect the internet by disable the network adapter(or similar way), server don't reserve any bytes that has been transmited previously. I don't want resume the session, I just want to reserve previous transmited bytes.

Comment: Re session, my point exactly. You have to start over. On the other hand what the server remembers of a partially uploaded file really depends on the FTP server implementation. Whether it supports appending to an existing file, also implementation specific.

Comment: @PepitoSh hi, I update my post, any suggestion?